# Election epilogue: one slight moddification

Tags: discussion, moderators

It's been a while since your [first election](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/election/1) ended. Your new mods have had some time to settle in, think about how they work together, and figure out the overall state of the Code Review stack. After all that, they decided that, as awesome as they are, they would be more comfortable with another team member to bounce ideas off of and generally share the load with.

And so here I am to announce that election runner-up janos is joining the ranks of the diamonded!

[image: janos]

Considering janos's activity level here and strong performance in the election, he should need no introduction from me, so I'll simply ask you to please join me in giving him a warm welcome to the mod team!

Comment: Was the misspelling on purpose? (`moddification` --> `modification`)

Comment: Yep! I was wondering how long it would be before someone commented on that (or made an well-intentioned edit that I would have to awkwardly roll back).

Answer (score 31):

## Thank You!

A big Thank You to everyone who supported me,
and who thought I'd make a fine mod.
I have much to learn,
but I'll work hard and do my best to live up to that!

Comment: Grats! I voted for you and was disappointed to see you just barely edged out. Glad to see this happened!

Answer (score 24):

Thank you @Pops for awarding the community a much needed 5th moderator.

Congratulations @janos on his new job! We all know you'll make a fine moderator, as proven by the latest election results. Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 19):

Congratulations Janos. I'm convinced you'll do an amazing job as our new master.