# Request to add an extra moderator given the 2021 election results

Tags: discussion, status-completed, moderators, election

Given we just had [the election](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10674/2021-community-moderator-election-results), after seeing how close the final results were (the final elimination was a margin of 0.04%), I would like to formally request that [Mast](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/52915/mast) be instated as a moderator.

Additionally, I want to note: [there is precedent for adding more moderators than open spots](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5975/election-epilogue-one-slight-moddification), and I believe that there are three justifications for doing this now:

1. This is [the tightest known margin of a Stack Exchange moderator election](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350981), and was decided by fewer than 1 vote;
2. Having more moderators, given the current global stress levels (pandemic, politics, et. al.) is *not* a bad thing;
3. Having an odd number of moderators (or any "officiating" body) is always a good idea so that a dead-tie (50/50) cannot be achieved;

Comment: For the record. I would like for Mast to be added as an additional moderator. If I have an idea I normally ask for Mast's opinion, and the current situation has made "you don't know what you have until it's gone" ring true for me. I would like to have the ability to bounce (moderator only) ideas off Mast.

Comment: Was it really decided by "fewer than 1 vote" ?

Comment: @user1271772 - effectively, yes, Sam was elected "easily", but in the race for 2nd place, the difference was much less than 1 vote, it was about a quarter of a vote, in fact.

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ When you originally asked to have more mods, did you ask for 3 or 2?

Comment: @user1271772 I don't believe _I_ originally asked to have more mods.... I know that there were 2 positions open in [election 3](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/election/3) due to the fact that [two moderators were stepping down](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10645/120114).

Answer (score 26):

We've discussed this request internally and with the moderators and we decided that there's universal support for this request and so I've just made Mast a moderator on this site, joining Sᴀᴍ Onᴇᴌᴀ and Peilonrayz as a third winner of the election.

Just to throw a few things out there... having an odd number isn't usually a big deal - most of the time, mods don't circle up and vote about actions, though they may ask for feedback before doing something - so *we* don't really take that into account.

We also don't really see the number of slots as "fixed" based on any metrics - so (for example) we don't say "y'all get 200 flags a month, and we expect 50 flags per mod per month, so you need four mods". We have the number of mods that are needed to get the work done. If the mods on a site are  comfortable with their workload with the number of mods they have - *that* is what's important.

If they feel like a new mod is needed for any reason, we'll see why they're asking and use that to prioritize scheduling an election. So, if they're getting bombarded with flags and someone just started a new job and needs quick relief, they might get an election right away. If there's a longer term "we'd like to have a new face on the team", it may wait a month or two.

Since y'all just had an election, it's easy enough to add a new moderator - as long as there's support for it and there's more candidates - what we set a pretty clear limitation on is that we can't "call up" the last person in an election - so if Mast had been the only other candidate, we wouldn't likely have added him to the team because we need elections to be competitive but, since there were two others, there's nothing preventing this on our end.

So, welcome to Mast - may you serve joyfully and well. :)

Answer (score 17):

Yes, Yes, Yes. many times during my terms as moderator, the discussions with the CM's requested 5 moderators. I am sure the discussion happened again before this election, and I am surprised that it was not implemented even before the election was announced.

Neither Jamal nor Malachai are frequent moderators, it's not uncommon for them to be away for days between visits, which leaves the balance of moderator activity in the hands of the remaining 2 moderators. The effect is that many days, there are just 2 moderators, and the addition of a moderator would be significantly helpful.

## Yes - post-add post-haste.

Update: I was prompted to revisit the history of moderation on this site. After the first election, we (the moderators) requested a 5th, [and @janos was included in the moderation team](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5975/election-epilogue-one-slight-moddification) (he was the next-in-line from the previous election).

If forget how it is that we went from 5, back down to 4.... I am surprised that we did not replace the full compliment of moderators at the next election.

Regardless, the precedent has already been established for both:

- elevating a runner-up in an election
- having a 5-member mod team

Comment: How many mods were there when the CMs requested 5 for discussions?

Comment: The CM's never requested 5, as far as I know. The mods requested that the CM's allow for 5 mods. I can recall at least 3 times where we we had discussions with the CMs about having 5 mods. I recall before each election (and I believe it is standard practice for the CM's to ask the mods at election time whether they are coping with the workload...). On each of those election occasions, I recall the discussion being that we thought 1 more would be good, but we did not have a compelling reason for "why". It's hard to justify when you're doing "OK", but not "great".

Comment: You know, I am digging through the history, we DID have 5 moderators at one point..... this is why history is important to record.... https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5975/election-epilogue-one-slight-moddification - going to edit my answer for this....

Comment: We went down from 5 to 4 when Simon stepped down

Comment: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9230/37660 you even wrote the relevant meta answer :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm just getting old... ;-)

Comment: No one even had to give the CMs their daily dosage of bad puns for them to add the 5th mod. Neither this time nor the last time :)

Comment: @Vogel612 Even I can't remember which four were left after I stepped down... mumble mumble getting old...

Comment: @Simon Me, rolfl, Malachi and Jamal. Then the whole CoC thing happened, rolfl stepped down and Mat jumped into the breach to keep things running... and then there was a year of the pandemic and that was that